# Place elements in custom places in Android

Tags: android, android-layout, imageview, imagebutton

I want to make an application that draws a layout with some background and then adds an Imageview and then adds some Image buttons on the Imageview in a specific places (x, y).

Can anyone tell me how to do that or a simple tutorial that may help me as I'm new to Android?

Comment: Please do some search effort before asking, thank you.

Comment: I did search in Dev Guide and i found some layouts like (Linear, Relative and Table) but none of them define a specific (x, y) except Absolute Layout and it is deprecated in the platform that I'm using 4.0.x so i thought that anyone can help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To place an element at a specific position, use an [AbsoluteLayout](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsoluteLayout.html)

Comment: The absolute layout is deprecated in API Level 15 for Android Platform 4.x , is there any other way

Comment: It is, but you never indicated that you want to develop for API level 15. That's not worth a bad vote. It's not a bad answer.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe reading [Android documentation about GUIs](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/index.html) is a good first step...